# Need to put points on overlapping boundaries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, intersection

I have two layers: a route (Line) and a county boundary (polygon).

I need to intersect them so that the output layer is a point layer. The ArcGIS **[Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000)** tool places a point where the route passes the county boundary.

But there are some locations where the route goes along the county boundary and then enters the boundary polygon. In such a case, ArcGIS fails to place any intersection point.

Is it possible to place two intersection points in such cases, one where the common segment starts and the other where the common section ends?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I just did some testing and I think I can reproduce what you are describing.  I recommend that you first include a diagram of your inputs, outputs and parameters in your question, and then submit it to your local support to ask if what you/we are observing is the expected software behaviour.  I think the page on [**How Intersect works**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/How_Intersect_works/00080000000z000000/) may need to be enhanced with your test case.

Comment: You are right. I tried to include a diagram but the website won't allow me to do so without having some number or reputation points.

Comment: Also, ESRI knows about this issue but have indicated that the tool does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can Buffer one layer and Intersect the other layer with the Buffer. Keep lines longer than a certain distance. These should be the coincident lines you speak of. You can convert the intersected line to end points.